# A counter-example for integration by parts when there are "small" singularities

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, geometric-measure-theory, singularity

I am looking for a "counter-example" to integration by parts of the following type:

$\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is an open, bounded, connected domain with **smooth** boundary. $u,v:\bar \Omega \to \mathbb R$ are real-valued functions, where $u$ is smooth and compactly supported in $\Omega$, and $v$ is smooth on an open subset of $\bar \Omega$ whose complement is a closed subset of measure zero. I want $\int_{\Omega}(\partial_iu)v \neq -\int_{\Omega}u(\partial_iv)$, i.e. to demonstrate failure of integration by parts.

**Edit:**

Does the answer change if we assume in addition that $v$ is continuous everywhere on $\bar \Omega$?. BigbearZzz gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3067295/104576) an example with a non-continuous $v$.

---

If $v$ was smooth on all $\bar \Omega$, then integration by parts would work. The point is that I am limiting the singular set to be closed and of measure zero. I guess integration by parts still cannot be saved, but I don't have a concrete example.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. For $n=2$, can't we just take the domain $\Omega$ to be the unit disk and $v=1$ for $x>0$ and $v=0$ for $x\le 0$ as a counterexample? Does this violate any of your assumptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a bit confused by the question, please tell me if I misread anything.

Consider the domain $\Omega=B_1\subset\Bbb R^2$, i.e. the unit ball. Define $v$ to be
$$
v(x)=\begin{cases}1 &; x<0 \\
0 &; x\ge 0.
\end{cases}
$$
We can see that $v$ is smooth on $\overline\Omega\backslash l$, where $l=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : x=0\}$ which is a closed set of measure zero.

Next, we take $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$. Since $\nabla v(x)=0$ a.e., we have
$$
\int_\Omega \varphi \partial_i v = 0.
$$
On the other hand, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\int_\Omega(\partial_1\varphi)v = \int_{-1}^1 \varphi(0,y)\, dy 
\end{align}$$
since the distributional derivative of $v$ is the Hausdorff measure on $l$.

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice example. I forgot to add the requirement that the singular function $v$ should be continuous on all $\bar \Omega$.  Do you think that it is still possible to get a counter-example? (I will accept your answer, but I am waiting to see if someone will add a counter-example assuming $v$ is continuous everywhere, or prove that no such example exist).

Comment: @AsafShachar The Cantor function is an example of a continuous function on $[0,1]$ that satisfies $f'(x)=0$ a.e. but has a (non-atomic) singular measure as its distributional derivative. This would be a counterexample you're looking for.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thank you. By the way, did you have a slick way to see that $\int_\Omega(\partial_1\varphi)v = \int_{-1}^1 \varphi(0,y)\, dy $ without computation? i.e. that "the distributional derivative of $v$ is the Hausdorff measure on $I$"? (By the way there is a small typo in your definition of $v$, it should be $x \ge 0$). Thanks for your all help!

Comment: One way would be to observe that for a fixed $y$ we have $\varphi(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^x \partial_x \varphi(t,y) \,dt$. Since $v=1$ on the left half plane and $v=0$ otherwise, we have $\varphi(0,y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \partial_x \varphi(t,y) \,dt$. Then we use the fact that $\varphi$ has compact support and Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Having look at it again, it is probably not what you'd call slick. I'll think of a better explanation.

Answer (score 3):

For a continuous counterexample, let's consider the case $\Bbb R^n=\Bbb R$ and $\Omega = (0,1)$. Let $v$ be the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)

[image: Cantor function]

It has the property that $v'(x)=0$ a.e., thus for any function $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(0,1)$ we have
$$
\int_0^1 \varphi v' = 0.
$$
On the other hand, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \varphi'v = -c_0\int_{0}^1 \varphi(t)\, d\nu(t) 
\end{align}$$
where $\nu=\mathcal H^\gamma\lvert_C$, the Hausdorff measure of dimension $\gamma= \ln 2 /\ln 3$ restricted to the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) $C$ (which is a compact set). Here $c_0$ is a normalizing constant that I don't remember.